# Trace/Breakpoint trap:delete []

Tags: c++, oop

I use VScode, and it shows "trace/breakpoint trap" on line:delete [] str;
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class String
{
private:
    char *str;

public:
    String() : str(new char[1]) { str[0] = 0; }
    const char *c_str() { return str; }
    String operator=(const char *s);
    ~String()
    {
        delete[] str;
    }
};
String String::operator=(const char *s)
{
    delete[] str;
    str = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
    strcpy_s(str, strlen(s) + 1, s);
    return *this;
}
int main()
{
    String s;
    s = "abc";
    cout << s.c_str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the code stops at the destructor :
delete [] str;
I wonder what is going on.

Comment: I don't see code, only an image. Pleas don't post images or links to images.

Comment: You should update your answer, instead of posting the code as a comment.

Comment: You didn't overload the copy constructor but this seems very necessary in your case (to prevent double deletes). FYI: [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: My previous comment in mind, please note, that your `String::operator=` has a weakness (which might be a typo or not): It returns `String` (which may cause a copying of the return value). Instead, it should return `String&`.

Comment: With that fix, it works: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae92f33a9abae5d2).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it's not my typo, just because I don't understand why it should be `String&`

Comment: Yes, just put `&` and it works.

Comment: However, with a proper copy-constructor even your (unlucky) original assignment will work: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7aa572d978fc2079). At best, you apply both fixes to your code. ;-)

Comment: The destructor is called when the `main` function finishes. As `String s` is defined in `main` block.

Comment: _I don't understand why it should be String&_ As I already told you: With return type `String`, the assignment operator has to return a value. For this, it may call the copy constructor of `String` for `return *this;`. With `String&`, you just return reference to `*this` - no copying at `return *this;`.

Comment: @HanjoungLee Yeah, but more important: If the assignment operator returns a temporary copy, the destructor is called for that instance also. That's why (and without a proper copy-constructor) there are two pointers `str` pointing to the same memory: one in `String s` and one in the temporary copy made by the assignment operator. Thus, the destruction of `s` at end of `main()` results in the double delete. The memory was already deleted with the temporary copy of `String`.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I wrote a temporary copy previously so str will be deleted twice. I can either write a deep copy copy-constructor or use `String &`.

Comment: For idiomatic code, you should do both.